# How to apply style to a PHP session variable that I'll echo if ISSET is true

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have this bit of code in my view:

```
<div>
    <?php
        if(ISSET($message))
            echo $message;
    ?>
</div>
```

Works fine for me. Except, when I try to edit this div in the following way, to apply style to `$message`:

```
<div class="msg done">
    <?php
        if(ISSET($message))
            echo $message;
    ?>
</div>
```

that style still remains in my view page, even after my session expires, or even if `ISSET($message)` is FALSE. Basically, I want this style to be applied ONLY WHEN `ISSET($message)` is TRUE and `$message` is displayed, and not otherwise.

The reference to this style is mentioned in my view page in the following way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
```

Inside main.css, the styling is done here:

```
.msg.done {background:url("../design/ico-done.gif") 10px 50% no-repeat;}
```

How can I only apply style to `$message` given that `ISSET($message)` is TRUE? I think my problem is: regardless of `ISSET($message)` value, my entire div is styled. That's why this style always remains there. Is there anyway I can get around this problem?

**EDIT - 1:**

I forgot to mention, this is a CodeIgniter application. My $message variable is a session variable which is coming from my controller - `employees.php`. My entire controller code is given bellow, maybe there's something wrong out there:

```
 <?php
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')){ exit('No direct script access allowed');}
class Employees extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //$this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('employee_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('session');
  }

  //Show all employees
  public function index()
  {
      //$data['employee_list'] = $this->employee_model->get_all_employees();

      //pagination codes
      $config = array();
      //$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin_logins/employee2';
      //$config['base_url'] = base_url('admin_logins/employee2');
      $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin_logins/employee2');
      $config['total_rows'] = $this->employee_model->record_count();
      $config['per_page'] = 10;
      $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
      $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
      $config["num_links"] = round($choice);


      $this->pagination->initialize($config);

      $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
      $data["results"] = $this->employee_model->
        fetch_employees($config["per_page"], $page);
      $data["message"] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
      $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

      $this->load->view('/admin_logins/employee_list', $data);

  }


  //Insert an employee
  public function insert_employee_db()
  {

      $edata['emp_id'] = $this->input->post('emp_id');
      $edata['emp_name'] = $this->input->post('emp_name');
      $edata['emp_mobile_no'] = $this->input->post('emp_mobile_no');
      $res = $this->employee_model->insert_employee($edata);
      if($res)
      {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Employee added successfully');
          header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/employees/".$this->index());
      }
  }

  //Edit an existing employee
  public function edit_employee_db()
  {
      $edata['emp_id']=$_POST['emp_id'];
      $edata['emp_name']=$_POST['emp_name'];
      $edata['emp_mobile_no']=$_POST['emp_mobile_no'];
      $res=$this->employee_model->edit_employee($edata, $_POST['emp_id']);
      if($res)
      {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Employee edited successfully');
          header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/employees/".$this->index());
      }
  } 
}
?>
```

**EDIT - 2:**

My latest try:

```
<?php
    if(isset($message)){
?>
<p class= "msg done">
    <?php 
        echo $message;
        unset($message);
    ?>
</p>
<?php
    }
    else {

    }
?>
```

But, still no luck.

**EDIT - 3:**

I've edited my code in the following way:

```
<?php
    if(ISSET($message))
        echo $message;
?>
```

It's working perfectly now, the message disappears once the session expires.

Also, if I edit it the following way:

```
<div style = "color: red">
    <?php
    if(ISSET($message))
        echo $message;
    ?>    
</div>
```

It works fine, and both the style and the message disappears upon session expiry.

But whenever I apply style to my div through external css file `main.css`, then I encounter the problem.

Comment: dear try my solution if it did not work i want to delete it. Thanks and let me know. its on the bases of your original question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Crescent Moon, Please use below code in your application.

```
<?php $style = (isset($message)) ? 'msg done' : ''; ?>

<div class="<?php echo $style; ?>">
    <?php
        //Print $message & unset appropriate session variable.
        if(isset($message)) { 
            echo $message;
            unset($message);
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

So As Per above code style is being only applied is $message is set otherwise your style not applied in to the div.

Let me know if you have still any issues.

Comment: It's not working, the style is still appearing. Note that $message is a session variable.

Comment: @Crescent Moon, After printing session variable,you need to unset that variable right after echo $messege; so session variable is unset and style also disappear from the page. Can you please give try ?

Comment: After `echo($message)`, I added `unset($message)`, but still the style remains out there.

Comment: @Crescent Moon, I have edit code as per your expectation,can you please try above code ? If It still not work then print your session after print message,may be session not destroy at your end!

Comment: I thought CodeIgniter session->flashdata is supposed to be destroyed after each browser request?

Comment: @Crescent Moon,Yes if you use codeigniter framework then you need to destroy session as per codeigniter standards. But Remember that not need to destroy after each browser request,you need to only reset after you print your session message so it will not appeared any more & also style disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        if(isset($message)){
    ?>
          <div class="msg done"><?php echo $message ?></div>
    <?php
        }
        else{
   ?>
          <div class="nothing">Nothing</div>
  <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Same problem, mate. The message disappears, but the style remains out there.

Comment: is you used anywhere in style display: none; ?